# Android SoundPool playing sound at different volumes

Tags: android, soundpool

I have a very strange problem that I can't figure out.  I have a soundpool initialized with a single sound (a very short 'click' sound).  In my onClick handler for my activity buttons I do a simple `SoundManager.playSound(1, 0);` which looks up the sound in a hashmap and plays the sound.  The exact same **playSound** call is used for every click.  It always plays the sound and hasn't erred.

Here is the funny part though.  The volume of the click sound changes from button press to button press.  I can press it once and it sounds faint.  I hit back and then press it again and it sounds loud.  I can't find any rhyme or reason to it.  I thought maybe it was getting messed up because of load (I know that is crazy but I am at a loss here) so I even started the sound in a separate thread.  Still the same result.  I thought maybe it was due to initializing the sound manager a second time, so I added a check to ensure that doesn't happen....same result.

I have used a sound manager class that I found several places on the web.  It is below.

```
public class SoundManager
{

    static private SoundManager _instance;
    private static SoundPool mSoundPool;
    private static HashMap<Integer, Integer> mSoundPoolMap;
    private static AudioManager mAudioManager;
    private static Context mContext;

    public static boolean isInitialized = false;

    private SoundManager()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Requests the instance of the Sound Manager and creates it if it does not exist.
     * 
     * @return Returns the single instance of the SoundManager
     */
    static synchronized public SoundManager getInstance()
    {
        if (_instance == null) _instance = new SoundManager();
        return _instance;
    }

    /**
     * Initialises the storage for the sounds
     * 
     * @param theContext
     *            The Application context
     */
    @SuppressLint("UseSparseArrays")
    public static void initSounds(Context theContext)
    {
        mContext = theContext;
        mSoundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 0);
        mSoundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        mAudioManager = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    }

    /**
     * Add a new Sound to the SoundPool
     * 
     * @param Index
     *            - The Sound Index for Retrieval
     * @param SoundID
     *            - The Android ID for the Sound asset.
     */
    public static void addSound(int Index, int SoundID)
    {
        mSoundPoolMap.put(Index, mSoundPool.load(mContext, SoundID, 1));
    }

    /**
     * Loads the various sound assets Currently hardcoded but could easily be changed to be flexible.
     */
    public static void loadSounds()
    {
        if (!isInitialized)
        {
            mSoundPoolMap.put(1, mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.click, 1));
            isInitialized = true;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Plays a Sound
     * 
     * @param index
     *            - The Index of the Sound to be played
     * @param speed
     *            - The Speed to play not, not currently used but included for compatibility
     */
    public static void playSound(int index, float speed)
    {
        float streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
        streamVolume = streamVolume / mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
        mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(index), 1, 1, 1, 0, speed);
    }

    /**
     * Stop a Sound
     * 
     * @param index
     *            - index of the sound to be stopped
     */
    public static void stopSound(int index)
    {
        mSoundPool.stop(mSoundPoolMap.get(index));
    }

    /**
     * Deallocates the resources and Instance of SoundManager
     */
    public static void cleanup()
    {
        mSoundPool.release();
        mSoundPool = null;
        mSoundPoolMap.clear();
        mAudioManager.unloadSoundEffects();
        _instance = null;

    }

}
```

You can see in the **PlaySound** method I have hard coded the volume for the left and right channel to the maximum value of 1.  This didn't help.  The volume of the sounds still fluctuates.

I also updated the stream I am using to `AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION` instead of `AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC` to see if it was somehow related to the stream.  It's doesn't appear to be as it exhibits the same behavior.

I have also converted my sound file from an `OGG` to a `WAV` to see if that helped.  No change.

It's a very quick 'click' that I am using but while listening closely it doesn't sound like it is getting cut off.  And the full file is being played.

Could this be hardware related?  The only test device I have used is an older HTC Incredible.  Any known problems with that hardware?

Again...the thing works but it is annoying to have the different volumes and I just can't let it go.  Has anyone else experienced this?